# Problem in connecting to Wi-Fi ,what is PSK?

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

When I am configuring Wi-Fi using "wifi_config" in Raspbian OS, there is a field called PSK which I should complete and I don't know what PSK means.  Can any one help me in resolving PSK and connect to Wi-Fi or at least suggest to me where can I can get that key?

Comment: How is your wifi network configured? Are you using WPA/WPA2? PSK (pre-shared key as @dastaan notes) is usually associated with WPA. Do you have other equipment besides the RPi connecting?

Answer (score 4):

`PSK` stands for `Pre Shared Key`. It is your wifi password.

Comment: yes ,Then i have used the wifi password and connected but at the authentication am getting "failed to  initiate AP scan" and when iam opening the browser (i.e) netsurf browser i am getting it an error message "no route to host"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is unfortunately, I bought 4 of these and cannot even get ONE to work. It is not as simply as 1, 2, and 3.  Any help would be great. Or I would like to return for a refund from this company. Will have to look into that.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/134492)

Comment: please delete this non-answer

Answer (score -1):

The key is on the back of your wifi Modem. Should be called "PSK", or "WPA2 KEY", Paraphrase"